# How to filter a PWM current source?

Tags: analog, pwm, filter, current-source

I am using the LMD18200 H-bridge to drive a DC motor using a 20kHz PWM signal. This chip has a current sensing output which produces a current of about 377uA per Ampere flowing through the motor (recirculating currents are ignored). I would like to read this output at around 100Hz using a 3.3v ADC.

*How can I simply and efficiently smooth out the current sense output ?*

I know how to use a low pass RC (or RL) filter to smooth out a voltage source but I am not totally sure of how such a filter would behave in presence of a current source. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you are familiar with the simple RC filter applied to voltage. One approach would be to consider the equivalent circuits below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxWwoq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The two circuits inside the two boxes are equivalent. So choose R1 to get the voltage range that you want. Now you can add C1 to form a familiar RC filter on the voltage.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I suspected but wasn't able to find any confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Using 377uA/A*2k7 load to gnd gives 1mV/A and output must not exceed 5V so this is a good value. Then use whatever is important, Avg DC current and peak I with a precision peak and hold with reset or whatever you want. Scale gain and condition filter to suit your requirements.